# change this text file in xml

Tags: xml, utf-8

I want to build test files from [www.unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org) manually in XML
How can I do it?
example code is here
part 1

```
# When other cursive scripts are added to the Unicode Standard in the
# future, the joining group value of all its letters will default to
# jg=No_Joining_Group in this data file. Other, more specific
```

Part 2

```
# Unicode; Schematic Name; Joining Type; Joining Group

# Arabic Characters

0600; ARABIC NUMBER SIGN; U; No_Joining_Group
0601; ARABIC SIGN SANAH; U; No_Joining_Group
```

Comment: What is your problem? What did you program so far? This site is to solve programming problems, not to solve problems in general (and we are not here to write programs for other people). In any case, I think you cannot do "generally" (it would not be useful). Every file has own set of test, and own problem, so different format and different information to give to user is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware that the Unicode database is available for download in XML format?

https://www.unicode.org/ucd/#UCDinXML